# Delete record in php and mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysql

l have created an application using php,html and mysql. The application can store a user's information such as id, name, bio, and date created into the database and display in html table. The id is an auto increment value which increases with every data entered by the user. The insert part of the application works fine but when l try to delete a record nothing happens. An html form is part of the code which l have intentionally decided not to include. Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
   $records = array();

 if(!empty($_POST)) {
    if(isset($_POST['firstName'],$_POST['lastName'], $_POST['bio'])){
    $firstName = trim($_POST['firstName']);
    $lastName  = trim($_POST['lastName']);
    $bio       = trim($_POST['bio']);

if(!empty($firstName) && !empty($lastName) && !empty($bio)) {
    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO people (firstName, lastName, 
    bio, created) VALUES (?, ?,?, NOW())");
    $insert->bind_param('sss', $firstName, $lastName, $bio); 

    if($insert->execute()){

        header('Location: addressbook.php');
        die();
       }

      }
      }
     }

  if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM people")){
  if($results->num_rows){
   while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
    $records[] = $row;
  }
 $results->free();  
}
 } 


 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <div class = "container">



<?php
    if(!count($records)){

    echo 'No records found';
    }

    else{


?>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Bio</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <?php
        foreach ($records as $r) {


    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo escape($r->id);?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($r->firstName); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($r->lastName); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($r->bio); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($r->created); ?></td>
            <td>
            <a  onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the 
          record')" href="addressbook.php?idd=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" 
          class="btn btn- 
          danger">Delete</a></td>



        <?php

        }
        ?>
     </tr>

 //My guess is the problem is with this code down here for deleting

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['idd'])){
        $idd = $_POST['idd'];
        $results = $db->query("DELETE FROM people WHERE id=$idd");
        if($results){
            header('Location: addressbook.php');
        }
    }
   ?>



  </tbody>
 </table>

   <?php

   }
   ?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['idd'])){` needs to be `$_GET` here, as you come from `href="addressbook.php?idd=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `$_GET` because by default `href` tag sends the data with `GET` method.
 your code should be

```
 if(isset($_GET['idd'])){
        $idd = $_GET['idd'];
        $results = $db->query("DELETE FROM people WHERE id='$idd'");
        if($results){
            header('Location: addressbook.php');
        }
    }
```

> NOTE- use prepared statement for avoiding sql injection attack

Comment: And beside that you should use prepared statements because that's a serious SQL-injection-hole there.

Comment: While this may solve OP's immediate problem, you should ***never*** delete anything via a GET request. Google will empty your database for you in no time flat this way…

Comment: I tried using the Get method as you suggested but still cannot get it work. If it helps, in the URL i get this after clicking on the delete button "http://localhost/addressbook.php?idd=".  I know l'm supposed to get the ID number in the URL when l click the delete button, but this has not happened.

Comment: that means id is not exist in url

Comment: @Jim `$row['id']`, `$r->id`…!?

Comment: @JimAdjei-Wiredu put it <a  onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the record')" href="addressbook.php?idd=<?php echo $r->id ; ?>" 
          class="btn btn- 
          danger">Delete</a>

Comment: because you have syntax error too here addressbook.php?idd=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>

Comment: change as i given above

Comment: @RahulShrivastava Thanks a lot, the delete works now.

Comment: glade to help you

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<?php
    //database connectivity


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

 mysqli_select_db($con,"<db_name>");
 $idd = $_REQUEST['idd'];
 $sql= "DELETE FROM people WHERE id='$idd' ";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
header("refresh:0.1; addressbook.php");
?>`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(isset($_GET['idd'])){
      $idd = $_GET['idd'];
      $results = $db->query("DELETE FROM people WHERE id='{$idd}'");
```

Try adding a single quote.
If it still doesn't work, please see if the $_POST is actually posting correctly.

Comment: I tried using the GET method but it still didn't work. I'm l doing something wrong?

Comment: try to echo something before the delete SQL

Comment: **please see if the $_POST is actually posting correctly.** No it will not posting correctly as the request is GET

Answer (score -1):

Try `$results = $db->query("DELETE * FROM people WHERE id=$idd");` instead of `$results = $db->query("DELETE FROM people WHERE id=$idd");` in the delete User Function :)